# login into application using jmeter api - couldn't login using jmeter API in java

Tags: java, jmeter, http-post

login into the application using JMeter API - couldn't login using JMeter API in java...

While trying to login into a web application using JMeter API by POST Method, getting the response like "Username/Password mismatch" even though providing valid credentials. I have no idea how Username/Password arguments are being parsed to the application using POST method. Please find my below code...

```
    URLRewritingModifier sess = new URLRewritingModifier();
    sess.setArgumentName("ci_session");
    sess.setShouldCache(true);

    CookieManager cook = new CookieManager();
    cook.getClearEachIteration();

    HTTPSampler postmethod  = new HTTPSampler();
    postmethod.setDomain("Name of the application");
    postmethod.setPort(80);
    postmethod.setPath("path of the page we are loading")
    postmethod.setMethod("POST");
    HTTPArgument args = new HTTPArgument();
    args.setValue("[{ \"username\": \"valid username\",   \"password\": \"valid pwd"}]");
    postmethod.addTestElement(args );
```

Could anyone help me at this point............

Comment: pwd"}]"); there's no backslash before the second to last double quotes, is it a typo?

Comment: by the way, I see a setCookieManager on HttpSampler in jmeter api (https://jmeter.apache.org/api/), did you add it somewhere?

Comment: Thank for the revert....

Comment: yeah i have corrected the backslash,dint give any result & I have added Cookie Manager in my Test plan which is essential,stores and sends cookies like a normal web browser would do if an actual user was hitting the server..

I feel like am missing HTTP Request Default Configuration in my test plan,which is going to be used by the following http request in the Test plan.I searched through the JMETER API document,not finding at all..any idea how to write HTTP Request Default Configuration in jmeter API using java...